# Merging specific set of row in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 9 columns and 2 of them are called `BREAKDOWNLEVEL` and `VALUE`.

I want for to merge the rows with `BREAKDOWNLEVEL == "15-19"` , and `BREAKDOWNLEVEL=="20-24"` to one new with label `"15-24"` and add their values.

I'm writing a complicated for loop, though i'm pretty sure there is a package suited for the job

Comment: post your attempts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` library and assuming your `data.frame` name is `df`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(BREAKDOWNLEVEL = 
  ifelse(BREAKDOWNLEVEL=="15-19" | BREAKDOWNLEVEL=="20-24", "15-24", BREAKDOWNLEVEL)) %>% 
  group_by(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, BREAKDOWNLEVEL) %>%
  summarise(VALUE =sum(VALUE)) %>% ungroup
```

in the `group_by` include all columns except `VALUE`

Comment: Your comment gave me a great lead , you were very helpful  . Thank  you also for the edit in my question , i might have to go straight to the how to ask section (<--newbie)